# Can't read power from this product description (10W + 10W notation)

Tags: power-supply, power, led-driver, led-strip

Here is the product in question: https://www.ledbe.com/24v-cob-tunable-white-led-strip

My question is: what does it mean by `Output Power: 5W+5W, 10W+10W, 15W+15W`? does that mean the power is variable between 5-10/10-20/15-30W? Or is it referring to the warm white and cool white diodes that are on the strip because it's a tunable strip between cool and warm white colors?

I am planning on using these COB LEDs to line my living room ceiling. it's around 88 ft in total, and I'm wondering if instead of running 2 small power supplies if I can run 1 big power supply for the ceiling. But for that I need to know the power and I can't figure it out from this product description.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: wattage probably has to do with tuning.  Usually a good idea to budget a significantly higher amperage for your supply anyway - I'd do 10W+10W = 30 to 40W in this case.  Can run multiple in parallel from one supply as long as the necessary amperage added up up can be provided by the supply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10W + 10W is implying the max power per channel. There are two channels, warm white and cold white, 10W each. So the real range is 0W to 20W, when both channels are fully on at the same time. And any power in-between when you dim either or both channels with a controller.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense.